# Is there any way for a function to know what property is being used?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a weird question that I'm unsure is possible.

I currently have this code

```
const creds = {
  username: "user",
  password: "pass"
}

function Keys() {
  // console.log(??); // I want this to print "username"
  return creds;
}

const usernameValue = Keys().username;
```

Is there any way for the function Keys() to know what property is being accessed inside the function? Is there some sort of magical `this` I can use?

My goal is log the key every time the Keys() property is being used.

I know that if I can do something like

```
const creds = {
  username: "user",
  password: "pass"
}

function Keys(key) {
  return creds[key];
}

const usernameValue = Keys("username");
```

But I rather not change the signature of this function since it's used by tons of people.

EDIT: Just to be clear, `creds` is actually a json file read. It's dynamic and has around 25 key/values that I rather not manually put into code

Comment: You can use getters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: The root concern is that no property is being used in the method.  The entirety of the method is to simply return the variable.  The step that accesses the property off of the result, does not happen inside that method, but after it returns.  So conceptually this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the object into getters and setters instead:

```js
const creds = {
  get username() {
    console.log('getting username');
    return this._username;
  },
  set username(newVal) {
    return this._username = newVal;
  },
  get password() {
    return this._password;
  },
  set password(newVal) {
    return this._password = newVal;
  },
  _username: 'user',
  _password: "pass"
}

function Keys() {
  return creds;
}

console.log(Keys().username);
```

You could also use a Proxy if the properties are dynamic and aren't known in advance, but they're slow and weird and probably shouldn't be used unless absolutely required.

For a Proxy:

```js
const proxy = new Proxy(
  {},
  {
    set(target, prop, newVal) {
      return target[prop] = newVal;
    },
    get(target, prop) {
      console.log('getting', prop);
      return target[prop];
    },
  }
);

proxy.user = 'foobar';
console.log(proxy.user);
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the properties are not only dynamic, but there's like 20 of them. So I rather not manually write it out. Would you be able to show an example of using a Proxy ?

Comment: Plenty of examples in the docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Holy you're a genius

Answer (score -1):

```
const creds = {
  username: "user",
  password: "pass"
}

function Keys(key) {
  console.log(key);
  return creds[key];
}

const usernameValue = Keys("username");
```

arf... sorry, i did not see that the signature of function could not be changed :/

Comment: I wrote I don't want to change the function signature